# Objects are not adding in NSMutableArray declared in other class Objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

In one of my class I have declared property as:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *arraySubviewImages;
```

Now I am accessing it from another class but objects are not added to it .

```
[parentImageView.arraySubviewImages addObject:childImageView]; // parentImageView is an object of first class
```

childImageView is the object in which all objects are present.

Comment: Did you `init ` your `arraySubviewImages ` in your custom class?

Comment: -(id)initWithImageArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayOfImages {
    
    if (self=[super init]) {
        _arraySubviewImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
    return  self;
}

Comment: Check please that your `parentImageView ` not nil in class where you added  `childImageView`

Comment: parentImageView is not nil.. I have checked that also

Comment: So, could you provide more code?! And how you `init` your `parentImageView` class did you use `initWithImageArray ` method?

Comment: try to put breakpoint at initWithImageArray and find if array is getting initialized or not

Comment: Don't post code in comments. It's unformatted and very hard to read. Please edit your original question and add more code. Include the headers of both classes in question, as well as the code where the second object gets access to an instance of the object that as the `arraySubviewImages" property.

Comment: array is getting initialized in initWithImageArray method. this also i have checked.

Comment: Something is likely nil when you don't expect it to be. It is valid to send a message to a nil object in Objective-C. It simply does nothing.

Comment: (lldb) po parentImageView.arraySubviewImages
 nil
(lldb) po parentImageView
<SUImageView: 0x7fbd84027890; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 0; 414 736); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbd81eb6750>>

Comment: this I am getting when I apply breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to initialize the array before using it :-

```
arraySubviewImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

After initializing the array you can add objects to your array(*make sure you initialize first for suggestion initialize it in ViewDidLoad*):-

```
[parentImageView.arraySubviewImages addObject:childImageView];
```

or you can do:-

```
arraySubviewImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithobjects:childImageView,nil];
```